# How to avoid null in Java method chain

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

Here is my code snippet.

```
     String fileName = "";
     FileDTO file = 
     FileService.findById(fileId);
    if(file != null && file.getFileFormate() != null){
        fileName = file.getFileName();
        fileName = "." +file.getFileFormate().getExtension();
    }
```

Here I can see chance of Null pointer exception. If file not null and then file.getFileFormate() not null then I can call file.getFileFormate().getExtension(). So I have to check null for each of them. Is there any flied way to check it. Something like:-

```
file?.getFileFormate()?.getExtension()
```

Also does JVM execute code from left to right for right to left?

So my code cold as check:

```
if(file != null && file.getFileFormate() != null)

or

if(file.getFileFormate() != null  && file != null)

or

if(null != file.getFileFormate()  &&  null != file)
```

Comment: Left to right & no. There is no other way. You have to chain it

Comment: Java doesn't have the `?` operator, you cannot check for `null` that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since presumably `FileDTO` is a class you've written, you can simplify your checks for null values like so:

```
if(file != null){
    fileName = file.getFileName();
    fileName = "." +file.getExtension();
}
```

And then add something like the following to `FileDTO`:

```
public String getExtension() {
    String extension = "";
    if (this.getFileFormate() != null) {
        extension = this.getFileFormate().getExtension();
    }
    return extension;
}
```

This has the added benefit of not exposing internal implementation details of `FileDTO`.

As for your other question, as the comment already said, it's left to right, but [some operators have an order of precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).